# Remove Row from DataTable using a custom button

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to remove the selected row using a custom button in dataTable `(datatables.net)`. I tried to follow the documentation but there is something that I don't understand. What I did is After I click `Approve` on confirmation pop-up I execute the code given on documentation `rows().remove()` but nothing happens.

**Here is my code:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var dataSet = [
                        [
                            "<div class='pull-right'>" +
                            "<br />" +
                            "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success' id='Approve' onclick='Approve(1)'> APPROVE </button> &nbsp;" +
                            "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' id='Decline' onclick='Decline(1)' > DECLINE </button>" +
                            "</div>" 
                        ]
                      ]

        $('#AccomplishmentTable').dataTable({
            data: dataSet,
            columns: [
                { title: "Employee" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

The **event** I'm trying to execute:

```
<script>
    $('#AccomplishmentTable tbody').on('click', '#Approve', function () {
        swal({
        title: "Approve this Accomplishment?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#5cb85c",
        confirmButtonText: "Approve",
        closeOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnCancel: true
        },
        function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                var url = "@Url.Action("Approve", "Utilities")";
                // $.get(url, { id: id }, function (e) {
                //     swal(e.MTitle, e.MBody, e.MType);
                // });
                console.log("Check");
                var table = $('#AccomplishmentTable').DataTable();
                    table
                    .row($(this).parents('tr'))
                    .remove()
                    .draw();
            } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:**
I'm using `ASP.NET MVC` and here is the UI of my code to avoid confusion

[image]

Comment: @Satindersingh I'm using `Asp.Net MVC`. I edited it my bad.

Comment: I believe the `c#` and `asp.net-mvc` tags is irrelevant here, and the .NET `datatable` tag should be replaced with the correct `datatables` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple scope problem, `this` refers to the embedded confirm function (or what it is), not the outer event handler. Do this instead :

```
$('#AccomplishmentTable tbody').on('click', '#Approve', function () {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  var api = $('#AccomplishmentTable').DataTable();

    swal({
    title: "Approve this Accomplishment?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#5cb85c",
    confirmButtonText: "Approve",
    closeOnConfirm: true,
    closeOnCancel: true
    },
    function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            var url = "@Url.Action("Approve", "Utilities")";
            // $.get(url, { id: id }, function (e) {
            //     swal(e.MTitle, e.MBody, e.MType);
            // });
            console.log("Check");
            api.row(row).remove().draw();
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue and tried couple of example but the best way found [here](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/inTableControls.html).

I have modified few things and it work for me

```
var tableOSList = $('#example').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 3,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": ["_all"] } //disable ordering events and takeout the icon
        ],
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "data": jsonObj,
        "columns":
            [
                {
                    "data": "imageName",
                },

                {
                    "data": "imageSize"
                },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<a href="" class="editor_remove"><span class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></span></a>';

                },
            ]

    });
}

$('#example').on('click', 'a.editor_remove', function (e) {

    if (confirm("Do you want to delete the file?")) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    }
   
});
```